# Инициализация указателя в классе значением по умолчанию

Tags: c++

Правильно ли я понимаю, что все члены класса, которые являются указателями автоматически при создании экземпляра класса инициализируются как NULL?
Замечаю, что в отладчике при первой строке вхождения в класс, даже this показывает как NULL.

Собственно вопрос еще о сфере применимости "данного феномена". Так всегда было, либо это со стандарта, вроде, с++ 11 и т.д.?
 
Интересно на сколько код написанный с использованием автоинициализации указателей нулем будет переносим соответственно (вроде использования delete на автоинициализированный указатель без всяких проверок).

На что-нибудь ещё распространяется инициализация начальными значениями по умолчанию?

Comment: Автоинициализации указателей нет. Вам просто везет, что память выделенная под объект забита нулями. Вызывать `delete` на нулевой указатель разрешено.

Comment: Зависит от способа инициализации объекта.

Comment: @ffk постоянно везет?) И если так, то какие могут быть причины везения (особенность моего компилятора, особенность моей машины, ...)

Comment: Если у вас "this показывает как NULL", то о каких значениях полей класса вообще может идти речь? Через такой `this` никаких осмысленных полей увидеть не получится.

Comment: Я имею ввиду, что если запустить отладку программы, то когда отладчик только заходит в конструктор класса и еще висит на самой самой первой строке, то `this` еще не успел проинициализироваться и поэтому он `NULL` еще. (Если перейти на следующий шаг отладчика, то значение, естественно, не `NULL`)

Comment: Некоторые отладчики любят обнулять все, что можно :) - и часто бывает, что в результате нормально проходящий отладчик код не работает в релизе...

Comment: @Harry Тоже в один момент так подумал, но при переключении с дебага на режим релиза ничего не поменялось...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, независимо от того, являются ли они членами класса и ли нет, указатели никогда сами по себе ничем не инициализируются, если вы их не инициализируете явно: или индивидуально, или каким-то общим внешним механизмом инициализации (напр. инициализатор для всего класса или нулевая инициализация статических объектов или объектов потока)

```
struct S
{
  int *p;
};

S g;                 // нулевое значение `g.p`

void foo()
{
  static S s;        // нулевое значение `s.p` 
  S a;               // неопределенное значение `a.p` 
  S v{};             // нулевое значение `v.p` 
  S *p = new S;      // неопределенное значение `p->p` 
  S *q = new S();    // нулевое значение `q->p` 
  thread_local S t;  // нулевое значение `t.p` 
}
```

> На что-нибудь ещё распространяется инициализация начальными значениями по умолчанию?

В языке С++ нет никакой "инициализации начальными значениями по умолчанию" для скалярных типов (кроме, как уже было сказано, инициализации статических объектов). Инициализироваться автоматически умеют только класс-типы с соответствующими конструкторами по умолчанию.

Comment: `class A {
public:
 int* a;
 A() {
  a == NULL; // true;
 }
};
int main() {
    A a;
}`
Можете пояснить, почему здесь не неопределенное значение получается `S s_a;             // неопределенное значение s_a.p` ?

Comment: @Дмитрий: Оно *неопределенное*. А то, что оно получилось null - не более чем случайность. Пробуем так: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c2cc62cc6dcedf6b И вот уже нам не повезло...

Comment: Хорошо, оно неопределённое. Просто случайность везде и на постоянной основе... Должна же причина быть, до которой и охота докопаться.

Comment: @Дмитрий: "Везде"? Я вам дал ссылку на пример, где добавил всего лишь еще один локальный объект - и от вашей "постоянной основы" и следа не осталось.

Comment: Интересно получается... Попробовал Ваш пример у себя позапускать в разных вариациях и везде все работает... Предположим, что у меня есть эта "постоянная основа", вообще, от чего такое может быть? (стоит MVS последней версии, скаченная с сайта майкрософта)

Comment: @Дмитрий: Ну никто не запрещает компилятору обнулять "новую" память. Но это странное занятие. Более того, MSVC++ как раз известен тем, что в отладочном коде специально забивает неинициализированную память ненулевыми значениями. В MSVC++ у меня все сразу падает.

Comment: Спасибо большое, вроде, исчерпывающе. Буду думать, что MSVC++ у меня химичит и следовательно такой код непереносим.